# Is there a way to show the following equality without induction

Tags: analysis

I wanted to show the following equality without using induction:

$$
\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k(k-1)} = \frac{n-1}{n}
$$

Any hint on how to do it?

Comment: *Hint:* $$\frac{1}{k(k-1)} = \frac{1}{k-1} - \frac{1}{k}$$

Write down the first few sums ($n = 2, 3, 4$) and see what happens.

Comment: Hint: what is $1/(k-1) - 1/k$?

Comment: *To all the hints*: Please note that using telescope sums just postpones the use of induction to showing that $\sum_{k=1}^n (a_{k+1} - a_k) = a_{n+1} - a_1$ (unless, of course, you have a non-induction way of showing that). I think it would be nice to have an answer which doesn’t suggest *hiding* the induction, but really has an idea of *avoiding* it.

Comment: I’m actually not even sure if it is possible to do that without induction, because finite sums are defined inductively. Maybe if you can give a non-inductive definition of finite sums …?

Comment: Yes, it's not obvious how to formally prove this result without using induction. @k.stm If you know of one, please give it.  What I took the question to mean is something like: "How can we get some insight as to why this result holds without using an inductive procedure that already assumes the form of the answer?" If that's not the intent of the OPer, please clarify that you are looking for a formal proof that does not use induction.

Comment: @SimonS Ok, that seems like a legit interpretation. One should nevertheless state that induction is still needed to prove the result when collapsing the telescope sum.

Comment: @SimonS I won't consider an index shift as "induction".

Comment: @user251257 I guess we have different definitions of 'formal proof' and that's ok. Depending on the context, what we require in terms of proof is different.

Comment: @SimonS Well, there is a difference between not writing down a formal induction for this specific question and ignoring that the set of natural numbers is inductive...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: use $\frac{1}{k(k-1)}=\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac 1k$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, $$\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{k(k-1)}$$ $$=\sum_{k=2}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}\right)$$ $$=\left(\frac{1}{2-1}-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{3-1}-\frac{1}{3}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{4-1}-\frac{1}{4}\right)+\ldots+\left(\frac{1}{(n-1)-1}-\frac{1}{n-1}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}\right)$$ $$=\left(\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}\right)+\ldots+\left(\frac{1}{n-2}-\frac{1}{n-1}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}\right)$$ $$=\left(\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{n}\right)$$ $$=\frac{n-1}{n}$$

Comment: But “$\ldots$” is hiding induction.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Partial fraction decomposition yields $$\frac{1}{k(k-1)} = \frac{1}{k-1} - \frac{1}{k}$$ which makes your series a special little beast called a *telescoping series*, try writing out the first few terms and see if you can spot a pattern that allows cancelling.

In particular, you get $$\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k(k-1)} = \sum_{k=2}^n \left(\frac{1}{k-1} - \frac{1}{k}\right)$$ Which, when written out term by term looks something like $$= \left(\frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{2}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4}\right) + \cdots + \left(\frac{1}{n-2} - \frac{1}{n-1}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n}\right)$$

Can you spot what cancels out?

Comment: By the use of “$\cdots$”, you are implicitly carrying out induction.